# Disable time/date pop up when scrolling

Tags: windows-8, touchpad, charms-bar

Recently installed Win 8. Sometimes on laptop, I will scroll left using touch pad, and the time/date box pops up on lower left. Have to click out of it to continue scrolling. Not sure what I am doing that activates that feature, but how do I disable that?

Comment: Which laptop model and what driver of touch-pad you are using?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable these gestures in the control panel applet for the touchpad:

1. Go into control
2. panel hardware and sound
3. mouse
4. touchpad settings

then disable the slide across gestures.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off the "charms bar" all together...

Go to control panel, appearance & personalization, task bar and navigation, navigation tab...
un-click the box that says "when I point to the upper right corner show the charms". click the apply button, click the ok button.

There are other ways to get to the control panel and settings, you do not need the charms bar and its damn clock.

Merry Christmas

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to control panel.
2. go to hardware and sound.
3. go to mouse.
4. go to device settings in mouse properties dialog box.
5. press settings... button.
6. make sure the box next to Enable Edge Swipes is unchecked.

This will vary from computer to computer but this should take you to the general area.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably swiping from the right edge of your laptop's touchpad which activates the charms bar. Windows 8 laptops have touchpad gestures as described [here](http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/windows-8-tip-use-trackpad-multi-touch-gestures). So what to do? Just make sure you don't swipe from the right edge of your touchpad and you'll be cool. OR you can disable the gestures from the settings of your touchpad driver's software